# install django bootstrap 3 for python 2.7 from source code

Tags: python, django, django-bootstrap3

python 2.7, I cannot connect to the internet with pip but if I download the source file or a zip I can use pip install

I want to install django-bootstrap3 here is the github page https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3

which file will allow me to install it correctly?

do I just download and stick it in my site-packages?

please be nice

Comment: `setup.py` is the file it operates against, you will need to clone the entire repository and run `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install` to install it

Comment: I get this `python: can't open file 'build': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: I updated the steps above, I had the wrong order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install` to install it.

Comment: Sure, no problem.